# How to add two primary key columns and same columns as foreign key in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I want to add two primary key columns and same columns as foreign key in sqlite table.

Like:

### table abc

```
aid integer,
bid integer,
primary key(aid,bid),
name text
```

### table xyz

```
xid integer,
yid integer,
primary key(aid,bid),

FOREIGN KEY(xid) REFERENCES abc(aid), 

FOREIGN KEY(yid) REFERENCES abc(yid)
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_composite), a multi-column foreign key constraint looks just like a multi-column primary key constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz(
    xid INTEGER,
    yid INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(xid, yid),
    FOREIGN KEY(xid, yid) REFERENCES abc(aid, bid)
);
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE "xyz" ("xid" INTEGER NOT NULL , "yid" INTEGER NOT NULL , "name" TEXT, PRIMARY KEY ("xid", "yid"),FOREIGN KEY("xid","yid") REFERENCES Item ("aid","bid"))  when i try to add data in xyz using sqlite manager in mozilla....xid field is highlighted as primary key (will autoincrement). But i don't want any autoincrement there.

Comment: SQLite Manager is wrong; a multi-column PK does not autoincrement.